# sed does not work after upgrading my Mac OS

Tags: macos, sed

After upgrading my Mac OS install some previous `sed` commands do not work for me:

```
GMC03-calculations $echo $line_no 
849
GMC03-calculations $cat corr.in
269 # number of clusters
845 # number of configurations
clusters 
...
...
```

I would like to replace the 845 (this is not a constant) into `$line_no` (in this case 849)

```
GMC03-calculations $sed -i '' 's/^[.0-9]* # number of configurations$/'"$line_no"' # number of configurations/' corr.in
sed: can't read s/^[.0-9]* # number of configurations$/849 # number of configurations/: No such file or directory
```

the following command works previously but not now.... very strange... I have installed sed using home-brew.....
G

```
MC03-calculations $brew install sed
Error: No available formula with the name "sed" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
gnu-sed ✔                                       libxdg-basedir                                  minised                                         ssed                                          
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install gnu-sed ✔
==> Searching taps...
These formulae were found in taps:
Caskroom/cask/focused                 Caskroom/cask/licensed                Caskroom/cask/marsedit                Caskroom/cask/physicseditor           Caskroom/cask/subclassed-mnemosyne  
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install Caskroom/cask/focused
```

Any idea what might be happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! By removing the `''` after `-i` :

```
sed -i '' 's/^[.0-9]* # number of configurations$/'"$line_no"' # number of configurations/' corr.in
```

Like this it all works again:

```
sed -i 's/^[.0-9]* # number of configurations$/'"$line_no"' # number of configurations/' corr.in
```

Everything seems to work perfect

Comment: What if you had used `/usr/bin/sed -i ' '  's........` ?